# 2012 Honda Civic Anti Theft

Tags: honda, battery, navigation

The battery on my 2012 Honda Civic died as I was away for 2 months. We charged the battery and its starting fine but the anti theft device won't stop making the car honk and lights flash. When I turned the car on it said to hold the power button to reboot which didn't do anything. I tried entering the radio code on my navigation touch screen device as I don't have preset buttons and that didn't work either. Not sure what I can do to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure if the Honda Civic has to have the new battery coded to the car, but some vehicles don't like new batteries which haven't been properly introduced.

Comment: I heard thats what happens when the alarm battery is low. never had to deal with it myself.